# Reading day of year without leading zeroes

Tags: python, datetime

I want to sort files that are named after the date, like **adq_2018_96_13_30_10.zip**, where the second number is the day of the year (without leading zeroes).

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
def keyfunc(value):
    return datetime.strptime(value, "adq_%Y_%j_%H_%M_%S.zip")

rate_file_list=sorted(glob.glob('adq_201*.txt'), key=keyfunc)
```

But I'm getting an error because **%j** reads the day of the year with leading zeroes. How can I solve this?

Comment: What error are you getting? `datetime.strptime('adq_2018_96_13_30_10.zip', 'adq_%Y_%j_%H_%M_%S.zip')` does not raise any error

Comment: ValueError: time data 'adq_2018_98_12_05_11.txt' does not match format 'adq_%Y_%j_%H_%M_%S.zip'

Comment: Oh, now I get it.

Comment: Because `.zip` does not match `.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `.zip` does not match `.txt`. `%j` can handle non-leading zeros numbers.

```
def keyfunc(value):
    return datetime.strptime(value, "adq_%Y_%j_%H_%M_%S.zip")
#                                                      ^^^^

rate_file_list=sorted(glob.glob('adq_201*.txt'), key=keyfunc)
#                                        ^^^^
```

See:

```
print(datetime.strptime('adq_2018_96_13_30_10.zip', 'adq_%Y_%j_%H_%M_%S.zip'))
# 2018-04-06 13:30:10
```